# Копирование файлов, для которых установлена защита от всех пользователей

Tags: linux, bash, unix

Нужно скопировать все файлы, для которых установлена защита от записи от всех пользователей. Имена копий генерировать путем добавления указанного префикса. Файлы-копии должны быть доступны для записи всем пользователям.

Как скопировать и изменять имена копий я представляю, однако никак не могу адекватно проверить защиту файлов от записи от всех пользователей

Comment: `$ if stat -c %A файл | grep -vq w; then echo да; fi`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Однострочник полностью решающий вашу задачу. PREFIX, пути и маски заточите под себя. По умолчанию чекаются все файлы в текущем каталоге и в текущий-же каталог записываются с префиксом "backup_"

`PREFIX="backup_";ls -l *|grep -E "^[-rwx]{8}-[-rwx]"|awk '{print $9}'|xargs -i sh -c "cp {} $PREFIX{}; chmod ugo+w $PREFIX{}";PREFIX=""`

Всё просто. Выводим листинг каталога в long формате. Грепаем начало каждой строки на нужный нам шаблон. Вырезаем 9-ю колонку у каждой найденой строки, что-бы взять имя файла. Отправляем файл на обработку -- копирование и изменение прав для копии.
Profit!

[image: Smart chmod]